# Virtual Storage Mount Notification BHO

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, internet-explorer

Virtual Storage Mount Notification {3532036A-BE08-43DC-9444-53022089DD96} is a valid BHO.

I have the BHO listed as {3532036A-BE08-43DC-9444-53022089DD96}' (with the ' at the end).

Is this still a valid BHO?